# How to create an attribute within an attribute in magento?

Tags: product, attributes, custom-options

I have a product that is about baby bedding set, customers can choose options.

First option is "FITS IN" and second one is "ITEM" however in every FITS In option I have different option of ITEMS and every ITEMS have different FITS in option. How to make product like that option with different options?

Answer (score 2):

You are describing the behaviour of a `Configurable Product`. You will need to set "Fits in" and "Item" as your configurable attributes, then in the `Associated Products` you can choose the combinations you are after.

There will be one simple product per combination.

Here's a bit more information about the subject:
http://www.sitepoint.com/adding-configurable-products-magento-ecommerce-site/

Comment: Thank You I have one more problem :(
But in attributes if I make price of 1 option like "Blue" is $100 and in another option its price is $50 it change $100 to $50. Can't I make price individually on each attribute option?

Comment: The final price will be the price of the combination you've picked. So if they pick "Blue" and "Large", the price will match the one you specified under the "Blue" "Large" product